# awk/sed filter example for column manipulation based on data in other columns

Tags: awk, sed, csv-simple

I am trying to find an example of how I may effeciently use sed or awk to manipulate csv data in a specific column (col 1 for instance) if the data in col 2 AND col 5 are not equal to "null".

Unfiltered example:

```
UNPOPULATED,NULL,DATA,DATA,NULL,DATA
UNPOPULATED,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA
UNPOPULATED,DATA,DATA,DATA,NULL,DATA
UNPOPULATED,NULL,DATA,DATA,NULL,DATA
UNPOPULATED,NULL,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA
```

would become:

```
UNPOPULATED,NULL,DATA,DATA,NULL,DATA
POPULATED,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA
UNPOPULATED,DATA,DATA,DATA,NULL,DATA
UNPOPULATED,NULL,DATA,DATA,NULL,DATA
UNPOPULATED,NULL,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
$2!="NULL" && $5!="NULL"{$1="POPULATED"}1' infile.csv
```

FS is the input **F**ield **S**eparator and OFS is for **O**utput **F**ield **S**eparator, both we set to a comma character at the **BEGIN**NING before processing the input file.

the we are checking if both of those columns (column#2 `$2` and column#5 `$5`) are not *NULL* value) `!="NULL"`, then update the first column value `$1="POPULATED"` and then with [idiom `1`](/q/63891/72456) at the end the input line will be output with all changes applied on it.

if you meant empty columns by NULL, then just compare against an empty string as following:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
$2!="" && $5!=""{$1="POPULATED"}1' infile.csv
```

Comment: like a virant `$2$5 != "NULLNULL"``

Comment: @nezabudka no, it will give a wrong result for when if one if them are null like `NULLdata` or `dataNULL` (data here means anything other than NULL) since OP clearly said `$2 AND $5`

Comment: @nezabudka, false negative with `NU` and `LLNULL`, too.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
k=open('filepath','r')
for i in k:
    gsplit=i.strip().split(',')
    if (gsplit[1] != "NULL"  and gsplit[4] !="NULL"):
        jk="POPULATED"
        print jk+","+",".join(gsplit[1:])
    else:
        print i.strip()
```

output

```
UNPOPULATED,NULL,DATA,DATA,NULL,DATA
POPULATED,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA
UNPOPULATED,NULL,DATA,DATA,NULL,DATA
UNPOPULATED,NULL,DATA,DATA,NULL,DATA
POPULATED,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA,DATA
```